# Заполнить combobox из map

Tags: c++-cli

Как правильньно заполнить комбобокс из `map`?

```
    map <int, byte> myFirstMap;///объявили map

    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(1200, 0x0C));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(2400, 0x18));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(4800, 0x30));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(9600, 0x60));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(19200, 0x13));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(38400, 0x26));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(57600, 0x39));
    myFirstMap.insert(pair<int, byte>(115200, 0x0B));

    for (auto it = myFirstMap.begin(); it != myFirstMap.end(); ++it)///вывод на экран
    {
        BaudRateCB->Items->Add(it);
    }
```

Comment: Откуда другие люди могут знать, что вы считаете правильным? Какое значение из пары - первое или второе - должно попасть в комбобокс? Или, может, сразу оба?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov первое значение

Comment: @Alexander Petrov,  Вероятно важен сам принцип, а не порядок значений.